# Write a program that asks the user for a file containing a program and a name for an output file.

Tags: python, text, formatting

Write a program that asks the user for a file containing a program and a name for an output file. Your program should then write the program, with line numbers to the output file. For example, if the input file is:

```
def main():
    for i in range(10):
        print("I love python")
    print("Good bye!")
```

Then the output file would be:

```
1   def main():
2       for i in range(10):
3           print("I love python")
4       print("Good bye!")
```

I know how to create a new output file but I have difficulty in adding lines to each line. please help! 
My program is:

```
filename = input("Please enter a file name: ")
filename2 = input("Please enter a file name to save the output: ")

openfile = open(filename, "r")
readfile = openfile.readlines()


out_file = open(filename2, "w")
save = out_file.write(FileWithLines)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `enumerate` to iterate through each line in the file:

```
for line_number, line in enumerate(readfile):
    new_line = ???        # make the new line by adding a line number
    readfile[line_number] = new_line
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate every line of input file by `enumerate` and write content to new file by string formating.

**input file**

input2.txt

```
def main():
    for i in range(10):
        print("I love python")
    print("Good bye!")
```

**code:**

```
filename = raw_input("Please enter a file name: ")
filename2 = raw_input("Please enter a file name to save the output: ")

openfile = open(filename, "r")
readfile = openfile.readlines()


out_file = open(filename2, "w")
for i , line in enumerate(readfile):
    out_file.write("%d %s" %(i+1, line))

out_file.close()
```

**Output:**

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow/anna$ python 7.py 
Please enter a file name: input2.txt
Please enter a file name to save the output: output2.txt
```

**Output file**

output2.txt

```
1 def main():
2     for i in range(10):
3         print("I love python")
4     print("Good bye!")
```

---

**with** statement.

```
filename = raw_input("Please enter a file name: ")
filename2 = raw_input("Please enter a file name to save the output: ")

with open(filename, "r") as fp:
    with open(filename2, "w") as fp2:
        for i , line in enumerate(fp.readlines()):
            fp2.write("%d %s" %(i+1, line))
```

---

**Note:**

Use `raw_input()` in Python 2.x

Use `input()` in Python 3.x